# Changing color of points in a particle system dynamically

Tags: three.js

I am iterating through points in a particle system, and changing a point's color when point satisfies a certain condition. Say I have to change color for jth point to gold:

```
var colors = particlesystem.geometry.attributes.color.array;
colors[3*j] = 0;
colors[3*j+1] = 40;
colors[3*j+2] = 255;
```

But I don't see change in color.

Is any thing extra is needed here?

I do as:

```
geometry.attributes.color.array[3*j] = r;
geometry.attributes.color.array[3*j] = g;
geometry.attributes.color.array[3*j] = b;
geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

But no change is reflected in particles' color.

Comment: Color values should be in the range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thanks for input. So I don't need to do anything like 'refresh'...just put these rgb values in 0 to 1  range?

Comment: `particlesystem.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
var colors = particlesystem.geometry.attributes.color;
colors.setXYZ(j, 0, 0.15, 1);
colors.needsUpdate = true; // when you change values of an attribute, set this flag to 'true'
```

Have a look at the documentation about [`THREE.BufferAttibute()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferAttribute).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var vertices = new Float32Array([-1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0
]);

geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.attributes.position.count; i++) {
  colors.push(1, 1, 1);
}
geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.25,
  vertexColors: true
}));
scene.add(points);

btnColor.addEventListener("click", function() {
  geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ(2, 0, 0.15, 1);
  geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
}, false);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<button id="btnColor" style="position: absolute">Colorify</button>
```

Comment: I tried this.It gives an error:Uncaught TypeError: colors.setXYZ is not a function

Comment: @Mandroid I've added a code snippet. Click the button to change the colour of a point. `.setXYZ()` works as expected.

Comment: @Mandroid Was it helpful?

Comment: Still same issue.I think I am using older version of Three.js, hence this method is not found.

Comment: Hey prisoner849, just a heads up that the code example is broken (clicking "Run code snippet" gives `geometry.addAttribute is not a function`) probably because the script URLs that you used aren't versioned. I.e. your code works for an older version of three.js, but the script tags load the newest version.